# IOS Swift - Why doesn't the image view appear in the default subtitle style TableCellView in the storyboard why is it different then the labels

Tags: ios, swift

If you use one of the default styles of a TableCellView you can see the labels in the interface builder in the view controller scene. But the image View can not be seen even tough it is an available object that can be set to contain an image (for the subtitle and plain style). Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

The imageView is only visible, if you assigned an image to it in the IB. If you don't assign an image, IB assumes that you don't want an image so it doesn't show it (otherwise an empty space would appear even if you don't have an image)

Comment: "otherwise an empty space would appear even if you don't have an image"   I am not sure why you are saying this I put an image view into a custom cell and I didn't populate it and I didn't see an empty space. I also put it into a regular view and didn't populate it and the was no blank space.

Comment: Ok, I think we're not talking about the Same thing: Have you asked an Image view manually or did you use the default image property?

Comment: I dragged an image view from the object library on to view controller. I did not modify any of the properties

Comment: Than the image view only displays an image if you assigned one. By default it is just transparent but exists. But you can't drag an image view into a cell with a basic or detail type.